# select only part of the input in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm reading a file from HDFS and I want to save it in another repository, with the DataFrame structure.
An example of my data:

> 05-09-2020 22:10:10, jony, abcd, usr.admin.local.teste

I want to send this data structure to another repository:

> 05-09-2020 22:10:10, jony, abcd, teste

When I make this code in spark scala everything is fine and everything works:

```spark
val read = sc.textFile("hdfs://.../teste.csv") 
val select = read.map(_.split(",")).map{x => (x(0),x(1),x(2))} 
val names = Seq("date","name","id") 
val df = select.toDF(names: _*)
```

But when I do this function, just to get "test" in the last argument, it gives an error

```
val read = sc.textFile("hdfs://.../teste.csv")
val select = linesConsumer.map(_.split(",")).map{x => (x(0),x(1),x(2),x(3).split(",")(3).replace(".", ","))}
val names = Seq("date","name","id","teste")
val df = select.toDF(names: _*)
```

The error it gives me is the following:

> ```
> ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 28.0 (TID 160) java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
>     at $line145.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:25)
>     at $line145.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:25)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
>     at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
>     at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 20/09/05 21:57:22 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 28.0 (TID 160, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
>     at $line145.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:25)
>     at $line145.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:25)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410) ...
> ```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: In the line x(3).split(",") you're trying to split the data in the format "usr.admin.local.teste" right? If so,why are you splitting by "," and not by "."?

Comment: I want to get the arguments separated by commas, but in the last argument I want to get the last argument that is separated by a point. I tried to do this: `val all = read.map(_.split(",")).map{x => (x(3).split(".")(3))}`  and it didn't work, giving the same error

Answer (score 1):

Your error occurred because you performed your `replace` *after* your `split`, when you probably meant to do it before. Which brings up: why not just split on `'.'` directly?
This approach adds more resilience by doing some simple length checks, and essentially skipping rows that cannot be parsed:

```scala
// return a list of one tuple for each successfully parsed line
val getRow = (s:String) => {
  val a = s.split(", *")
  if (a.length == 4) {
    val lastList = a(3).split('.')
    val last = if (lastList.length > 0) { lastList(lastList.length - 1) } else ""
    List((a(0), a(1), a(2), last))
  } else List() } 
val df = sc.textFile(csv_path).flatMap(getRow).toDF("date", "name", "id", "teste")
```

Assuming this input:

```
05-09-2020 22:10:10, jony, abcd, usr.admin.local.teste
05-09-2020 12:10:10, vas, saga, usr.admin.local.champ
05-09-2020 20:10:10, nema, abd, usr.admin.local.mora
```

This would be `df.show(false)`:

```
+-------------------+----+----+-----+
|date               |name|id  |teste|
+-------------------+----+----+-----+
|05-09-2020 22:10:10|jony|abcd|teste|
|05-09-2020 12:10:10|vas |saga|champ|
|05-09-2020 20:10:10|nema|abd |mora |
+-------------------+----+----+-----+
```

Since the date is still just a string, you may need to convert it, depending on what you'll do with it.

#### Edit for additional question in comment

To omit the string after `'@'`, if such a character exists in the string, introduce a new value `lastBefore` and use `String`'s `indexOf` and `substring` methods:

```scala
val getRow = (s:String) => {
  val a = s.split(", *")
  if (a.length == 4) {
    val lastList = a(3).split('.')
    val last = if (lastList.length > 0) lastList(lastList.length - 1) else ""
    val lastBefore = if (last.indexOf('@') >= 0) last.substring(0, last.indexOf('@')) else last
    List((a(0), a(1), a(2), lastBefore))
  } else List() }
```

Comment: If my last argument has yet another delimiter, how can I do it? If my input is `05-09-2020 22:10:10, jony, abcd, usr.admin.local.teste@123` and I still want to just get this `05-09-2020 22:10:10, jony, abcd,teste`and forget everything that is in front of @, how can I do it? Could you edit your answer to this new problem?

Comment: Please look at edit (Also, try to get the question as complete as possible next time, to avoid edits).

Answer (score 0):

You are splitting the row on comma, and then try to split x(3) on comma; x(3) won't contain any commas due to the first split so will give ArrayIndexOutOfBounds on all indices except 0.

Comment: I wanted to divide the 3rd argument by point to get the last value, but I'm not able to do that

Comment: That's not what your code does above, you are dividing the third argument on comma, so that is probably your problem!